# How can I create and execute a series of PHP Variable Functions in a for loop?

Tags: php, function

I'm unfamilar with using `variable functions` in PHP, but I've repeatedly re-read the manual:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

and it's not at all clear what I'm doing wrong here:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {

  $Function_Name = 'Test_Function_'.sprintf('%03d', $i);

  function $Function_Name() {

    echo  __FUNCTION__.' is working.';
  }

  $Function_Name();
}
```

Why is this loop not creating and running 10000 variable functions?

---

### Alternative using anonymous functions

An alternative approach (using anonymous functions) doesn't seem to work either:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {

  $Function_Name = 'Test_Function_'.sprintf('%03d', $i);

  ${$Function_Name} = function () {

    echo  __FUNCTION__.' is working.';
  }

  ${$Function_Name}();
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? I see no possible way this could actually be useful.

Comment: I am setting up a speed test. Creating and running 10,000 functions will give me the baseline. Then I will compare against creating and including 10,000 files containing functions. Then I will compare against creating and `eval()-ing` 10,000 strings.

Comment: you cannot define a function with a variable. You must use the name of the variable `function Function_Name() {`

Comment: You could just use anonymous functions. `$some_function = function() { /* do stuff */ }` and then call `$some_function();`

Comment: Thanks, @NiettheDarkAbsol. Before I posted I did attempt an alternative approach using anonymous functions (now added to the question above) but I couldn't make that work, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that anonymous (lambda) functions only see (closure) variables from the external scope if they are explicitly listed with "use" i.e.

> ${$Function_Name} = function () use ($Function_Name)

and then it works as expected.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) 
{    
  $Function_Name = 'Test_Function_'.sprintf('%03d', $i);
  ${$Function_Name} = function () use ($Function_Name)
  {
    echo  $Function_Name.' is working.'.PHP_EOL;
  };
  ${$Function_Name}();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant work, Stefanov.sm. @NiettheDarkAbsol was also right that I should use an _anonymous function_, which I'd tried, but what I'd missed in my own test (and still visible in my question at the top) is that I had failed to demarcate the end of the assignment with a `;`. Your tip regarding `use` is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: More on deploying `use` in this context here: https://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/04/07/php-use-keyword.html